# google login working in without headless but not with headless mode

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-signin

im trying to login into my google account using python selenium with chromedriver,
the code works but not in headless mode. in hm i get the the identifierId never appears :(

EDIT: added missing --disable-gpu

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

def do_login(email, password):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')
    email_phone = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='identifierId']")))
    email_phone.send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
    pw = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']"))
    )
    pw.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(driver.title)
    driver.close()
```

should login like in non headless mode

Comment: Are you receiving an error message that indicates to you that the code is not working? Could you post that error message here so we can better troubleshoot your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add `--disable-gpu` to your chrome options.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

That's what I had to add to get my headless code fully working.

Answer (score 0):

I always pass below arguments, Tested and works:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works in headless mode but not with gui enabled

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

def do_login(email, password):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')
    email_phone = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Email")))
    email_phone.send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id("next").click()
    pw = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Passwd"))
    )
    pw.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()
    driver.close()
```

Comment: "This code works in headless but not in non headless" -- does the code work in headless mode or not?

Comment: I ran this code in my environment and it ran without issue -- what error message are you encountering here that indicates to you the code is not working?

Comment: sorry this is the working code i just found it. the code in my initial post was not working

Comment: I'm confused about the issue you are having here. Did adding `--disable-gpu` get your code to work in headless mode? Your code is probably not working because 'Email or Phone' field does not have ID = 'Email'.

Comment: no when i open the google sign in page with gui active the id of the email field is 'identifierId' when i browse the same page in headless mode the id of the email field is 'Email', --disable-gpu was just missing due to a copy and paste mistake. only need it to be working in headless so im fine

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the page you are automating, and not an issue with headless mode -- your best bet here is to debug and view the driver page source while running in headless mode to see what elements are actually on the page.  If a web page displays different elements based on the presence / absence of a browser, that's not an issue that headless options can solve.